# how to convert this date form to unix time

Tags: php

I have this date form

```
Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:49:25 +0100
```

I am thinking of using php internal function strtotime. I was trying to split and relocate each string however it is too much lines. If you have any better way to do  it. Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `strtotime` works fine with that string. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea. Go with your instincts:

```
<?php
  $mydate = 'Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:49:25 +0100';
  $unixtime = strtotime($mydate);
  // If you want to display the time, uncomment the next line:
  //echo $unixtime;
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass this to strtotime.

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert date to timestamp.
[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert back timestamp to date.

Check this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:49:25 +0100');
print $timestamp . "\n";
print date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);
```

Output:

```
1378993765
Thursday 12th of September 2013 01:49:25 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

**strtotime** is very unreliable. Your absolute best option is to use the [built-in DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime). The difference is that you'll have to create a date object first with:

```
$mydate = 'Thu, 12 Sep 2013 14:49:25 +0100';
$d = date_create_from_format('D, d M Y H:i:s P', $mydate);
```

and then output it back out in Unix format with:

```
$u = date_format($mydate, 'U');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ts = strptime ("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z") ; 
$ts = mktime($ts['tm_hour'], $ts['tm_min'], $ts['tm_sec'], $ts['tm_mon'] + 1, $ts['tm_mday'], $ts['tm_year'] + 1900);
```

%z will not work on Windows (see http://php.net/strptime)